# pdftohtml outputting low resolution background images. help?

Tags: server, pdf, conversion, html

runnning:

```
pdftohtml -c document.pdf output.htm
```

this returns the normal output but the background images are of such low quality
they cannot be read.

Is this a bug with pdftohtml or can I change a config 
file somewhere?

any help would be much appreciated, cheers :)

running:
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure but see if your problem is due to this bug http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/RybTrtkbz0vNyQrK1IlX

That said what you are doing even without bugs, is fraught with potential output disasters, PDF is a complex document format usually not intended to be converted to other formats, it is principally for display and printing as is.

Text and picture extraction is easy with the same tool you mentioned without the -c switch which tries to preserve the look of the original PDF,

I would say try to convert without using the -c switch,this will likely get you good enough images but the layout may not be what you want, but maybe you could create something to fix it up. you may not have to fix anything if the PDF is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can configure it, but you could try using Openoffice with the pdf-import extension to do your conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

But I'm looking to use it on a webserver, with a php script calling pdftohtml. This is a lightweight approach and OpenOffice sounds clunky